# <type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'>(Invaild table/column name "Date" is a "All" reserved SQL/NOSQL keyword

Tags: web2py

```
db.define_table('Bill',
                Field('Bill_NO', 'integer', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('Date', 'date'),
                Field('Customer_ID', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('Name', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('Address', 'text', length=255),
                Field('Phone', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('Item', 'list',  requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()), Field('Price', 'list`', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('Grand_Total', 'double', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY())
                #auth.signature
               )
```

I have typed the above code and I got the following error after clicking on db.Bill in models,
(Invaild table/column name "Date" is a "All" reserved SQL/NOSQL keyword
So help me out to get rid of this error. Thanks.

Comment: Check this http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer?search=reserved#Reserved-keywords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `Date` in your web2py code but don't mind if the database uses an alternative name, you can do:

```
Field('Date', 'date', rname='bill_date')
```

In that case, the database will use `bill_date` as the column name (therefore avoiding the reserved keyword error), but in your web2py code, you can still refer to `db.Bill.Date`.

Answer (score 1):

Because Date is a datatype in SQL database, if you want to make it as your column name replace it to [Date]

Comment: Your answer is wrong. I'm got the following error as per your answer, <type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'>(Field: invalid field name: [Date], use rname for "funny" names)

Comment: He's tip to work around the problem is wrong, the rest is correct as per your original error message, "Date" is a reserved word, you cannot use it without escaping it. Also, "Date" is an entirely wrong name conceptually as it doesn't state *what* it is the date of. If this is the "due date", then you should name it like that, or if it is the "billing date" you should name it like that, ie. `BillingDate` or `DueDate`. As to how you should go about working around the limitation similar to what JC tried to suggest, I don't know, that depends on the database engine in question.

Comment: Check this http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer?search=reserved#Reserved-keywords